# How to fix ios error making request to /1/files_put/auto/captr.(NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)

Tags: ios, dropbox

Instead of playing around it with timeout,its better we can redirect file which fail to uploads,using uploadFileFailedWithError delegate of Dropbox api.

i did the following to upload multiple files on drop box.

-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {

```
NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error.userInfo);

NSString *myfile=[error.userInfo valueForKey:@"sourcePath"];



[self.restClient uploadFile:@"youfilename" toPath:@"/yourfilepath" withParentRev:nil fromPath:myfile];
```

}

This way the files which couldn't upload will get re attempt to get uploaded..

Comment: Is there a question here?